# "I like to DO sport" vs "I like to MAKE sport"

Tags: word-choice

Should I use "do" or "make" when I refer to sport?

> "I like to **DO** sport"

or

> "I like to **MAKE** sport"

Comment: To ***make sport** [of someone/something]* is a dated / archaic usage meaning to mock them (or otherwise amuse yourself at their expense). You can ***do** sport*, meaning ***engage, participate** in sport* . Or you could simply say *I like sport* - but depending on context that might mean you just like *watching other people* engaging in sports (singular or plural makes little difference there).

Comment: @FumbleFingers At Dictionary.com, (certainly no laggard in declaring words out of date!) definition No. 6 is "mockery; ridicule; derision." "They made sport of him" is presented as an example usage without any indication that it is archaic or dated. Use it myself when appropriate, and no-one calls me a fuddy-duddy or tries to fit me with a merkin.

Comment: @P. E. Dant: Your profile gives no details, but I'm guessing you're no teenager! Per [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=made+sport+of%2Cmade+fun+of&year_start=1850&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmade%20sport%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmade%20fun%20of%3B%2Cc0) *to make sport of* was eclipsed by *to make **fun** of* over a century and a half ago. Out of interest, I drilled down to the ***sport*** results for 1960 - 2000. Only a couple of dozen anyway, but a surprisingly high percentage had a *religious* context, which may be significant.

Comment: @FumbleFingers True, I've been shaving for decades. Religious writing seems to preserve older usages for some reason - in the case of Catholicism, sometimes entire languages!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Make** would never be used with "sport" in this context. To "make sport of" has a distinct meaning in English: to mock, ridicule, or make fun of.

**Do sport** (note the singular noun) is a usage you might see or hear in Great Britain or the Commonwealth countries, and it is perfectly acceptable. It may be less common than the standard usage in North American English, which is **play** (or, in Great Britain and Commonwealth countries, **play at**) with the plural "sports":

> I like to **play** (at) sports!

Comment: You could say "I like to do sport at school" quite happily.

Comment: @Monkjack One could say it happily, and properly, but it would be a very uncommon usage stateside, and even in blighty. As much as I detest ngrams, yet see [link](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=do+sport%2Cplay+sports&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=0&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdo%20sport%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cplay%20sports%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: You've just shown that x is more common than y. Not that y is wrong. So what's that got to do with it? English is full of repetition !

Comment: @monkjack Precisely! I chose "commonly" in my answer with a clear knowledge of what that word connotes.  I don't see a claim that "do sport" is "wrong." If that claim is in my answer somewhere, I'll remove it.

Comment: Ok, but I guess your answer, to me, reads as "unlikely to be heard" :)

Comment: @monkjack Does it seem _likely_ to you? Don't you think you are much more likely to hear _I like to play sports!_ than _I like to do sport!_ ?

Comment: Yes agreed. I just don't think it would come across as wrong that's all. And maybe I'm imaging it, but I think your answer can be read as saying that do would almost never be used, rather than the literal usage of commonly.

Comment: Let me add a bit more, all I really mean is, if someone said to me "I make sport" I'd think instantly - not a native speaker. If someone said "I do sport at school" I wouldn't bat an eyelid. Maybe it's a dialect thing - Buckinghamshire England here, or maybe it's because it seems natural with, "I do English at school, I do Maths, I do Sport"

Comment: @monkjack Here comes the dreaded Chat Invitation... well, obviously, when I have a moment, I should expand my answer to incorporate your and FF's comments.